# Check for version number after string and error if no version number found

Tags: bash, grep

Currently looking for a better way of doing this...

Say for example I had a file that contains a string with either a branch name or version number. I would like to catch if the file does not use a version number after the `ref` pattern.

example file:

```
source = "git::https://URL?ref=main"
source = "git::https://URL?ref=0.1.0"
```

Currently I am doing it like so:

```
# Search for string after pattern and turn it into an array.
version=($(grep -oP '(?<=ref=).*' file.txt | tr -d '".'))

# If array does not contain number pattern, catch it.
if [[ $version =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}$ ]]
then
  echo "All module sources contain versions, will continue"
else
  echo "Some module sources DO NOT contain versions, you must use a version number in your module source"
fi
```

How can I do this with grep alone, or even with having to export the string to an array?

Comment: I'm not sure I grok the problem, but can't you just check if the inverted match is empty? `if [[ $(grep -v 'ref=[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}' file.txt) == '' ]] `

Comment: Yea that's another way to avoid the variable array: 

if [[ $(grep -Po 'ref=\d+(\.\d+)*' file.txt | tr -d 'ref=.') =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}$ ]]
then
  echo "All module sources contain versions, will continue"
else
  echo "Some module sources DO NOT contain versions, you must use a version number in your module source"
fi

Answer (score 0):

```sh
if grep -E 'ref=[0-9].[0-9]{2,3}$' file.txt; then
   echo has version
else
   echo has no version
```

Comment: Tried this, just says "has no version" when I include version numbers in the example above.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the filename in the grep command.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with

```
if [[ $(grep -oPr '(?<=ref=).*' | tr -d '"') =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}$ ]]
then
  echo "All module sources contain versions, will continue"
else
  echo "Some module sources DO NOT contain versions, you must use a version number in your module source"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With a GNU `grep` and PCRE regex, you can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
rx='ref=(?![0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}")[^"]*"'
if grep -Pq "$rx" file.txt; then
  echo "Some module sources DO NOT contain versions, you must use a version number in your module source"
else
  echo "All module sources contain versions, will continue"
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lHzwf0). The regex means

- `ref=` - a `ref=` text
- `(?![0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}")` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more digits followed with two or three occurrences of a dot and one or more digits
- `[^"]*"` - zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char.

Answer (score 0):

Grep has an `--invert-match` option (aka `-v`), so you can look for lines that *do not* match your pattern and if that search succeeds you'll know you have non-compliant lines:

```
if grep -vqE 'ref=\d+(\.\d+)*"' file.txt; then
    echo "Some module sources DO NOT contain versions, you must use a version number in your module source"
else
    echo "All module sources contain versions, will continue"
fi
```